# What is the best way to reset an array of integers in vhdl?

Tags: arrays, vhdl, reset

I'm fairly new to vhdl and I don't find a good solution to this trivial-looking problem. I'm looking for a good way to reset an integer array.

```
type integer_vector is array (0 to N) of integer;
...
process(...)
variable tab: integer_vector;
...
if reset = '1' then
 tab := ??
```

Is there something similar to `tab <= (others=>(others=>'0'))` which works for `std_logic_vector`? I don't want to use a for-loop since the synthesis doesn't support this.

Comment: Synthesis - most synth tools - can support `for` loops, as long as they obey certain rules, for example, they have a "locally static" range, such as constant loop bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morten's code looks OK, so please mention the synthesis tool and version which reports this. Some synthesis tools may be too primitive to accept this code : in other cases there may be synthesis options to turn on the necessary behaviour. (Also check you followed his instructions precisely : `(others => 0);` asks for integers, while `(others => '0');` asks for bits).

However, for synthesis, note two things:
(a) ranged integers would be better; it's trying to generate 32-bit integers (though later stages of synthesis may trim them)

So for example.

```
subtype my_int is natural range 0 to 99; -- needs 7 bits
type my_int_vector is array ( 0 to N) of my_int;
```

may yield smaller hardware,  and certainly makes it clear to the reader that smaller integers are expected.

(b) in order to reset the entire array in a single operation it'll need to implement the whole lot in registers, which can produce a huge piece of hardware.

If you arrange to reset one location per clock cycle (usually in a state machine), with a counter indexing through the whole array, then the array can be implemented as a block memory, saving a lot of space.

Comment: Thank you for the deeper insight into this issue. (b) was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

When the element of an array is `integer`, you can do:

```
tab := (others => 0);
```

The inner `(others=>'0')` in your example assigns `'0'` to all `std_logic` elements in each `std_logic_vector` of an array, so when the element is `integer`, this is simply `0`, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! This solution works perfectly for simulations but my synthesis is still not happy with this one: "Width mismatch. <tab> has a width of 320 bits but assigned expression is 10-bit wide."